# Multiple duplicate rows in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am working on a database system using oracle 10g designer and sqlplus
There are multiple queries I have to create, most with easy but some I having some problems.

I have a query here that when runs returns 204 rows of data when it should in fact be returning 17 rows of data. The rows seem to repeat itself 12x times. I cant wrap my head around this; it has been hours. I am submitting my code, a screenshot of how the query supposed to look (the scs form), my ERD, a screen shot of the results and the explain plan table output. The repeating rows are a result of the last 10 columns.

Can anyone help?

```
COLUMN C_FNAME FORMAT A10
COLUMN C_LNAME FORMAT A10
COLUMN C_ORG FORMAT A35
COLUMN C_ADR FORMAT A35
COLUMN C_CNUM FORMAT 9999999
COLUMN E_ID FORMAT A7
COLUMN E_NAME FORMAT A35
COLUMN E_FTIME FORMAT A21
COLUMN E_STIME FORMAT A21
COLUMN ET_DESC FORMAT 10
COLUMN V_NAME FORMAT A30
COLUMN V_ADDRESS FORMAT A35
COLUMN V_CNUM FORMAT 9999999
COLUMN D_DESC FORMAT A30
COLUMN D_AMT FORMAT A3
COLUMN ST_DESC FORMAT A15
COLUMN S_FNAME FORMAT A15
COLUMN S_LNAME FORMAT A15
COLUMN EQ_TYPE FORMAT A15
COLUMN EQ_DESC FORMAT A15
COLUMN EQ_AMT FORMAT A3
COLUMN SU_NAME FORMAT A40
BREAK ON C_FNAME ON C_LNAME ON C_ORG ON C_ADR ON C_CNUM ON E_ID ON E_NAME ON E_STIME ON E_FTIME ON ET_DESC ON V_NAME ON V_ADDRESS ON V_CNUM ON D_DESC ON D_AMT ON EQ_TYPE ON EQ_DESC ON EQ_AMT ON SU_NAME
SELECT C_FNAME, C_LNAME, C_ORG, C_ADR, C_CNUM, E_ID, E_NAME, E_FTIME, E_STIME, ET_DESC, V_NAME, V_ADDRESS, V_CNUM, D_DESC, D_AMT, ST_DESC, S_FNAME, S_LNAME, EQ_TYPE, EQ_DESC, EQ_AMT, SU_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER, EVENTTYPE, STAFFTYPE, VENUE, EVENT, STAFF, EVENT_DISHES, EVENT_EQUIPMENT, EVENT_STAFF, DISHES, EQUIPMENT, SUPPLIER
WHERE E_ID ='E000001'
AND CUSTOMER.C_ID = EVENT.C_C_ID
AND EVENTTYPE.ET_ID = EVENT.ET_ET_ID
AND VENUE.V_ID = EVENT.V_V_ID
AND EVENT_DISHES.E_E_ID = EVENT.E_ID
AND EVENT_DISHES.D_D_ID = DISHES.D_ID
AND EVENT_EQUIPMENT.E_E_ID = EVENT.E_ID
AND EVENT_EQUIPMENT.EQ_EQ_ID = EQUIPMENT.EQ_ID
AND EQUIPMENT.SU_SU_ID = SUPPLIER.SU_ID
AND EVENT_STAFF.E_E_ID = EVENT.E_ID
AND EVENT_STAFF.S_S_ID = STAFF.S_ID
AND STAFF.ST_ST_ID = STAFFTYPE.ST_ID;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am fairly new to sqlplus. I am learning as i go along

Comment: Could you provide an execution plan?  Try executing 'explain plan for <your query>', then when it completes, do 'select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);'.  Add the output to your question.

Comment: good day. thank you for your response. I have added the requested information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier if you restructure your query to use the ANSI compatible join syntax, instead of = in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT C_FNAME, C_LNAME, C_ORG, C_ADR, C_CNUM, E_ID, E_NAME, E_FTIME, E_STIME, ET_DESC, V_NAME, V_ADDRESS, V_CNUM, D_DESC, D_AMT, ST_DESC, S_FNAME, S_LNAME, EQ_TYPE, EQ_DESC, EQ_AMT, SU_NAME
FROM customer
INNER JOIN event ON CUSTOMER.C_ID = EVENT.C_C_ID
INNER JOIN eventtype ON EVENT.ET_ET_ID = EVENTTYPE.ET_ID
INNER JOIN venue ON EVENT.V_V_ID = VENUE.V_ID
INNER JOIN EVENT_DISHES ON EVENT.E_ID = EVENT_DISHES.E_E_ID
INNER JOIN DISHES ON DISHES.D_ID = EVENT_DISHES.D_D_ID
INNER JOIN EVENT_EQUIPMENT ON EVENT.E_ID = EVENT_EQUIPMENT.E_E_ID
INNER JOIN EQUIPMENT ON EVENT_EQUIPMENT.EQ_EQ_ID = EQUIPMENT.EQ_ID
INNER JOIN SUPPLIER ON SUPPLIER.SU_ID = EQUIPMENT.SU_SU_ID
INNER JOIN EVENT_STAFF ON EVENT.E_ID = EVENT_STAFF.E_E_ID
INNER JOIN STAFF ON STAFF.S_ID = EVENT_STAFF.S_S_ID
INNER JOIN STAFFTYPE ON STAFFTYPE.ST_ID = STAFF.ST_ST_ID
WHERE E_ID ='E000001';
```

I'm looking into the reasons why your data is incorrect now, but this is a place to start.

I think there's an issue in the join to the event_equipment and suppliers table. Is the data unique in that table?

Comment: Good day sir i have tried your solution and the result is the same 204 rows returned. Unique? well the event_equipment table holds the ID of each event, the ID of each equipment and the amt of the equipment used per event.

Answer (score 2):

The 204 rows returned are the correct amount resulting from your query.
You have 17 staff personal (where the type is only derived from). Those 17 rows are multiplied with the 2 dishes and multiplied with the 2 hired and 4 required (2+4 = 6) equipement. So 17 * 2 * 6 gives you 204 rows.

This is because e.g. the EVENT_DISHES is queried to fill the 17 so far existing rows with results that matches the given E_ID and returns the 2 d_d_id's each time.

I think your goal was to create the form you provided programmatically. To achieve this you need to query your database four times. Once for the event itself, once for the dishes, once for the equipement and once for the staff related to the event.

```
SELECT C_FNAME, C_LNAME, C_ORG, C_ADR, C_CNUM, E_ID, E_NAME, E_FTIME, E_STIME, ET_DESC, V_NAME, V_ADDRESS, V_CNUM
FROM event
INNER JOIN customer ON EVENT.C_C_ID = CUSTOMER.C_ID
INNER JOIN eventtype ON EVENT.ET_ET_ID = EVENTTYPE.ET_ID
INNER JOIN venue ON EVENT.V_V_ID = VENUE.V_ID
WHERE E_ID ='E000001';

SELECT D_DESC, D_AMT
FROM EVENT_DISHES
INNER JOIN DISHES ON DISHES.D_ID = EVENT_DISHES.D_D_ID
WHERE E_E_ID ='E000001';

SELECT EQ_TYPE, EQ_DESC, EQ_AMT, SU_NAME
FROM EVENT_EQUIPMENT
INNER JOIN EQUIPMENT ON EVENT_EQUIPMENT.EQ_EQ_ID = EQUIPMENT.EQ_ID
INNER JOIN SUPPLIER ON SUPPLIER.SU_ID = EQUIPMENT.SU_SU_ID
WHERE E_E_ID ='E000001';

SELECT ST_DESC, S_FNAME, S_LNAME
FROM EVENT_STAFF
INNER JOIN STAFF ON STAFF.S_ID = EVENT_STAFF.S_S_ID
INNER JOIN STAFFTYPE ON STAFFTYPE.ST_ID = STAFF.ST_ST_ID
WHERE E_E_ID ='E000001';
```

I hope I matched all the fields correctly to the corresponding query. Revise as you need.

Comment: This approach also avoids the need, that **every** component has to exist before an event is shown, caused by the (implicit) INNER JOINS.

Comment: Thank you very much sir this helped alot